# String ID in OData

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

Is there any way to use string ids in OData?

For example, if I have user entity, I would like to have ids like this:

```
"users/1"
"users/123"
etc...
```

Am I limited by the protocol or I just cannot make it work with WCF?

For now, I m facing problem with get entity by id:

```
/DataService.svc/Users('users/1')
```

as it raises an error.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post discusses this at length - but in general it's considered not a good idea as there are security implications.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peter_qian/archive/2010/05/25/using-wcf-data-service-with-restricted-characrters-as-keys.aspx

Comment: Does not work for me... And there are comments about .NET 4.0 and 4.5 saying the same: does not work. Any more ideas?